# <include> layout does not have the right size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-wrap-content, android-include

I'm creating a layout_banner.xml that is referenced by multiple other layouts, and has a height of 80dp.

layout_banner.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#4455ff"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Banner test"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview:

[image: Banner layout]

However, once I add this layout into another using <include>, the height isn't the expected value:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/layout_banner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/planner_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/banner_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview:

[image]

Why is the banner shorter than 80dp when referenced with include? The include object has height set to wrap_content so shouldn't layout_banner.xml be able to take up as much height as it needs?

---

UPDATE: Thanks to the responses so far, removing the width and height from the include layout fixes the size issue, but unfortunately that also makes any constraints be ignored. For example, in the below layout, the banner is 80dp as expected, but should be going below the recyclerView, not over it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/planner_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
        layout="@layout/layout_banner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/planner_recyclerview"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so that the height of the banner is `80dp` remove `layout_width` and `layout_height` of include

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue, but it creates another one. When I remove width and height, any constraints are ignored, for example if I try putting the banner below a fixed-height recyclerView. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Try to set the height above include and not above the banner

Comment: like this     <include
        android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
        layout="@layout/layout_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/planner_recyclerview"
        />

Comment: I see, but that defeats some of the purpose of using <include>, as I was looking to define the height in just one place, instead of every time the banner is referenced. However, I suppose I can set the height in dimens.xml and have the <include> blocks use that for height, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! PS: if you use a LinearLayout you will not have this problem

Answer (score 1):

On your `activity_main.xml` you are overrinding `layout_width` and `layout_height` of your `layout_banner.xml,` just do:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
    layout="@layout/item_agregar_pedido"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue, but it creates another one. When I remove width and height, any constraints are ignored, for example if I try putting the banner below a fixed-height recyclerView. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Can you post an image of your desired design? Or the edited .xml ?

Comment: I have updated the question with a new XML that has the constraints issue.

Comment: From other posts, it seems it's not possible without setting width and height, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676415/how-to-include-constraint-layout-to-another-constraint-layout-and-set-constraint)